# I keep getting an error when declaring a variable inside a loop. what's the problem?? (C)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char input[100], output[100];
    gets(input);

    for(int i=0, a=0; i<strlen(input); a++)
    {
        char word = input[i];
        output[a] = word;
        if(word == 'a' || word == 'e' || word == 'i' || word == 'o' || word == 'u') i+=3;
        else i+=1;  
    }

    output[a] = '\0';    
    puts(output);
}
```

It says a is not declared, but didn't i declare it in the loop?
How to declare a variable inside a loop without getting an error?

Comment: Stop using `gets` immediately, it has been removed from the language because it has no bounds checking.

Comment: `a` (and `i`) goes out of scope when the `for` loop ends. Declare `int a = 0;` _before_ the `for` loop if you need it _after_ the `for`  loop

Comment: The scope of the variable is the loop body. You can't access it outside.

Comment: ... and as @Barmar mentioned: Never use `gets`. Use `fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);` instead (and check the return value).

Comment: I suggest that you read this: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/12149471)

Comment: `if (!fgets (input, sizeof input, stdin) { return 1; } input[strcspn (input, "\n")] = 0;` is your replacement for `gets()` that also trims the `'\n'` from the end of `input` by overwriting with the null-byte.

Comment: What type is 'a'?

Answer (score 2):

### Local scope :

In

```
for(int i=0, a=0; i<strlen(input); a++)
```

`a` goes out of scope, or is destroyed, once the loop exits.

**From C11:**

> For such an object that does not have a variable length array type,
> its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is
> associated until execution of that block ends in any way.

**Fix:**

Declare `a` outside the loop.

---

### Using gets():

The function `gets()` is inherently dangerous, and has been removed from the C standard. It provides no bounds checking and can potentially cause a buffer overflow.
Instead, use `fgets`.

See: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/20017547)

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8fa198fcM) with the issues fixed

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because you're using `a` outside the body of the loop:

```
output[a] = '\0';
```

`a` is only visible within the body of the `for` loop, and once the loop exits it no longer exists.

The easy way to deal with it is to declare `a` before the loop:

```
int a = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < strlen( input ); a++ )
  ...
```